# How to create Custom field in Custom Post-type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I've a custom post-type "video" and i enabled custom fields already.
i need to create three custom fields, 1. video file, 2. video url, 3. video code.
i tried couple of tutorials on tutsplus and other sites but not get working as i need.
anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a built in api function, [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) which you can use to output the form fields for your post meta. in the post_type argument you need to put 'video'

In order to capture the form input you need to use the save_post action, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151409/wordpress-save-post-action-for-custom-posts)

Comment: Thanks LobsterMan yeah i follow this and create a custom field now

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). You'll have a nice interface to add your custom fields and to choose on which post type to show them.