# how to create a wordpress plugin that adds additional input fields to the Write/Edit page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, input

I am writing a plugin that requires additional information from the use when they create a post. I need a text box that they will enter a number that can have decimals and a drop down box that will give a few options. I also need this data to be saved with the rest of the post data in the wordpress DB. Can someone give me some help with this?

P.S. i will later need to add an area to the post itself when displayed that shows a piece of data calculated from the plugin but first things first.

EDIT:
i got the first part done but now i can't get the new fields to save data with the post, here is my code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Column Height Calculator
Plugin URI: #
Description: calculates the height of the column
Version: 0.1
Author: Ben Crawford
Author URI:
*/

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_post_options_box');

function my_post_options_box() {
add_meta_box('post_info', 'Column Height Info', 'custom_post_info', 'post', 'side', 'high');
}

//Adds the actual option box
function custom_post_info() {
global $post;
?>
<fieldset id="mycustom-div">
<div>
<p>
<label for="column_type" >Column Type:</label>
<br />
<select name="column_type" id="column_type">
  <option value="JBC">Justified Body Copy</option>
  <option value="LRC">Left Raggid Copy</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
<label for="header_size">Header Size:</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="header_size" id="header_size" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'header_size', true); ?>">
</p>
</div>
</fieldset>
<?php
}

add_action('save_post', 'custom_add_save');
function custom_add_save($postID){
// called after a post or page is saved
if($parent_id = wp_is_post_revision($postID))
{
$postID = $parent_id;
}

if ($_POST['column_type']) {
update_custom_meta($postID, $_POST['column_type'], 'column_type');
}
if ($_POST['header_size']) {
update_custom_meta($postID, $_POST['header_size'], 'header_size');
}
}

function update_custom_meta($postID, $newvalue, $field_name) {
// To create new meta
if(!get_post_meta($postID, $field_name)){
add_post_meta($postID, $field_name, $newvalue);
}else{
// or to update existing meta
update_post_meta($postID, $field_name, $newvalue);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Indenting the code properly makes it *thousands of times easier to read and debug*. You can find many examples of working code in [wordpress.se], check [this search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2badd_meta_box%20%2bsave_post%20is%3aanswer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own meta boxes using the [add_meta_box()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) wordpress function. This will give you the most control.

But if you are just using this metabox to save data with the post, then you could incorporate [this Github project](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) into your plugin. That would make it very easy to add some data fields that save post meta data. You can then get this meta data in the loop with [get_post_meta($post->ID)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

Comment: I figured out the add_meta_box part now i just need the data they entered to be saved with the post so i can access it later from the loop.

Comment: well for your project I strongly recommend using the project on Github I link in my answer, as it does exactly what you want to do. However to build it yourself you need to [add an action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to the save_post hook. [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151409/wordpress-save-post-action-for-custom-posts#6270232) has some code that might help.

Comment: i think i added a hook for that, i added my code above. It stil won't save.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, the data was saving in postmeta and not post. It all works now, that was the easy part now i need to add the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

[github.com/CMB2/CMB2](http://github.com/CMB2/CMB2) - this is new plugin version. Look wiki [wiki](http://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki) Yoa can crate such as in example:

```
/**
 * Initialize the metabox class.
 */
function cmb_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes()
{
    if (!class_exists('cmb_Meta_Box')) {
        require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '../CMB2/init.php');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'cmb_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes', 9999);
add_action( 'cmb2_admin_init', 'cmb2_sample_metaboxes' );
/**
 * Define the metabox and field configurations.
 */
function cmb2_sample_metaboxes() {

    // Start with an underscore to hide fields from custom fields list
    $prefix = '_yourprefix_';

    /**
     * Initiate the metabox
     */
    $cmb = new_cmb2_box( array(
        'id'            => 'test_metabox',
        'title'         => __( 'Test Metabox', 'cmb2' ),
        'object_types'  => array( 'page', 'post'), // Post types
        'context'       => 'normal',
        'priority'      => 'high',
        'show_names'    => true, // Show field names on the left
    ) );

    // Regular text field
    $cmb->add_field( array(
        'name'       => __( 'Test Text', 'cmb2' ),
        'desc'       => __( 'field description (optional)', 'cmb2' ),
        'id'         => $prefix . 'text',
        'type'       => 'text',
        'show_on_cb' => 'cmb2_hide_if_no_cats', // function should return a bool value

    ) );
}
```